# resize logo on mobile devices

Tags: css, responsive-design

My logo is not resizing on mobile devices and therby my menu overlaps the logo. I've hard coded the css property for my logo for desktop screen since I want my logo to appear big on desktop but i want it to resize on mobile devices and I have set setting for it but it does not work, kindly please tell me what is the best solution or what i'm doing wrong, how can i fix it.

```
    .logo {}
    #logoimg {
              width:250px; height:70px; transition: all .3s ease;
             }

/*============= media query max-width: 768px; =============*/

@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {

  /* start query */
  .header { padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;}
  .logo img {width:auto;}
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve], including HTML and valid CSS. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to put a runnable snippet here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please clean up your code and be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
img {
  width: auto ;
  max-width: 100% ;
  height: auto ;
}

/*============= media query max-width: 768px; =============*/

@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
/* start query */
.header {
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.img  {
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- logo -->
    <div class="col-md-12"> 
    <a href="index.html"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/91/National_Film_and_Television_School_Logo.jpg" alt="logo"></a> </div>
    <!-- logo --> 
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div id="navigation"> <!-- navigation start-->
        <ul>
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a> </li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it shrinks the logo on small devices but on large screen it does not maintain the 250px width and height

Comment: <!-- logo -->
    <div id="logoimg" class="logo">
     <a href="index.html"><img src="cssnew/images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
     </div>
    </div>
    <!-- logo -->

     <div class="col-xl-9 col-lg-9 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
      <div id="navigation">
       <!-- navigation start-->
       <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a> </li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </div>

Answer (score 0):

use class img-responsiv
 
It will help you